# Can't install Bower components using Grunt - "Arguments to path.join must be strings"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, bower, bower-install

I'm having issues installing Bower components using my Gruntfile.js. I can however install the Bower components fine using Bower command.

Installing Bower components using Bower command works fine.

> bower install

I cannot however install Bower components using Grunt command

> grunt bower:install

Hers's some details.

bower.json:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.2",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "latest",
        "bootstrap": "latest",
        "lodash": "latest",
        "font-awesome": "latest"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "latest"
    }
}
```

.bowerrc:

```
{
    "directory": "libs",
    "json": "bower.json"
}
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
bower: {
    install: {
        options: {
            install: true,
            copy: false,
            targetDir: './libs'
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to install Bower components using Grunt, I get the following errors:

```
Running "bower:install" (bower) task
...
bower validate 1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
bower new version for git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
bower resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#*
Fatal error: Arguments to path.join must be strings
```

Does anyone see what is wrong with my Gruntfile.js file and why I get this error when installing Bower components using Grunt?
Thanks.

Comment: Would updating your bower version help? Or are you on the latest?

Comment: I'm using grunt-cli v0.1.13 and grunt v0.4.5. I think that is the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I have my configuration which is working for me:

```
bower: {
            install: {
                options: {
                    targetDir: bowerDir,
                    install: true,
                    cleanTargetDir: false,
                    cleanBowerDir: false,
                    bowerOptions: {}
                }
            }
        }
```

Also make sure you have the dependencies in your package.json file:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-bower-task": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-cli": "^0.1.13",
```

also try running these commands:

```
npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
npm install grunt-bower-task --save-dev
```

Comment: Your configuration looks very similar to mine. Copying your config didn't fix it. I also have devDependencies in my package.json file.

Comment: what's your bower version ? Can you post your bower.json file ?

Comment: bower is v1.6.5. I"ve posted my bower.json file above.

Comment: also try running these commands:

    npm install grunt-cli --save-dev
    npm install grunt-bower-task --save-dev

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how your suggestion fixed the issue, but it has. Can you explain why you suggested using: npm install grunt-cli --save-dev npm install grunt-bower-task --save-dev and how this solved the problem?

Comment: this link has a good explanation of npm saving packages locally - https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally