# Can't run my grunt task using grunt-bower-task plugin

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I've the same configuration like this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578322/cant-install-bower-components-using-grunt-arguments-to-path-join-must-be-str) in my gruntfile.

```
bower: {
        install: {
            options: {
                targetDir: './lib',
                install: true,
                cleanTargetDir: false,
                cleanBowerDir: false,
                bowerOptions: {}
            }
        }
    }
```

But wen I run my grunt task it throw the following error:

```
Running "bower:install" (bower) task
Fatal error: No bower.json present
```

That's a little weird because I've my bower.json file inside of the defined directory(lib). Also if I run inside of it throw the same error

Any suggestion?

Comment: did you tried running bower install from command prompt? How did you generated your project scaffold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried running bower install from command prompt? How did you generated your project scaffold?  Bower.json , package.json and gruntfile.js should be in your root directory.

Here is the best way to generate project scaffold and running the application using grunt and bower.

http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, I run it from terminal. By the way you answer help me because I didn't realize to have my bower.json in the same place which package.json and gruntfile.js. I've my bower.json inside of another directory on the root of the main directory. There are the html files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bower.json needs to be in the same directory as your package.json/gruntfile etc. not in the target directory.

Comment: I tried to run it in the same directory but didn't work.